# SOAP over JMS Service on EAP 7

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jboss-eap-7

I'm trying to deploy a war file on a Jboss EAP 7 AS.
The file contains a SOAP over JMS webservice, including a WSDL description. (Relevant part below)

```
    <soapjms:jndiConnectionFactoryName>java:jms/RemoteConnectionFactory</soapjms:jndiConnectionFactoryName>
    <soapjms:jndiURL>http-remoting://localhost:8080</soapjms:jndiURL>
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:SoapBinding" name="WebServicePort">
        <soap:address location="jms:queue:MyQueue"/>
    </wsdl:port>
```

Unfortunately I always get the following error during the deployment process:

```
 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (default I/O-1) AMQ224018: Failed to create session: ActiveMQSecurityException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=AMQ119031: Unable to validate user: null]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.security.impl.SecurityStoreImpl.authenticate(SecurityStoreImpl.java:134)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.createSession(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:985)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQPacketHandler.handleCreateSession(ActiveMQPacketHandler.java:150)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQPacketHandler.handlePacket(ActiveMQPacketHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.handlePacket(ChannelImpl.java:626)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.doBufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:349)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:331)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(RemotingServiceImpl.java:616)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:68)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at org.xnio.netty.transport.AbstractXnioSocketChannel$ReadListener.handleEvent(AbstractXnioSocketChannel.java:435)
    at org.xnio.netty.transport.AbstractXnioSocketChannel$ReadListener.handleEvent(AbstractXnioSocketChannel.java:371)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:88)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:559)
```

I had the same behaviour using EAP 6.4, which uses HornetQ as Message Broker.
HornetQ offers the possibility to simply turn off the security system in the EAP-configuration file.

```
<security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
```

But I did not find any solutions for EAP 7, which uses Apache ActiveMQ instead.

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a working solution by adding the username and password to the JMS URL.

```
<soap:address location="jms:queue:JISQueue?username=serviceuser&amp;password=EasyPW12"/>
```

But that's not what I actually was looking for, because now everyone can see the credentials in my WSDL contract.

Is there a possibility to append these information to the CXF security context programmatically?